# How to setup Android SDK 2.0?

Tags: android

I've installed Android SDK latest version. There is Android versions 1.5, 1.6, 2.1-update, 2.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.3 and 3.0 on "Installed Packages" of ADV Manager.

But here is not listed 2.0. I want to develop my app on 2.0(Level 5).

How to install OS 2.0 to AVD Manager ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android SDK 2.0 (API level 5) is obsolete, so you should NOT develop against that SDK. However, you can install it by running `android`. Then under Available packages, uncheck "Display updates only," and you should see all of the SDKs up there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, Should I use Android 2.1 instead of it ? As I can see, it is not obsolete.

Comment: Yeah Android 2.1 (API Level 7) should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to disagree with what Frank said because it has merrit, but in general, I suggest developing against the lowest version of the API which will support your application fully to not alienate anyone with older versions of the OS running.

There's a nice write up at http://www.mobiusbay.com/home/android%E2%80%93day0gettingstarted

This will guide you through the entire setup process if you have any issues!

### Good luck!

Adam