# how to add the new api level in android?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am using Android API level-8(i.e. Android 2.2 Froyo). I want to add the new api level-5 ( i.e. Android 2.0 Eclair).

I have updated avd manager but the api level-5 can't display.

When I import the project in workspace the right click the project select android tools and fix the Project properties then Display this type error in console

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-5'
```

Comment: Finally i got the answer Nothing Do anything just change the Project.properties file as you choose api level and also change the  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> in manifest file in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clarify what you mean by add.

If you mean add another OS image, then you should use the Android SDK Manager.
In the package name you should find the Android 2.0. If you didn't have it installed, then install it and create a new OS Emulator with this OS version.

There's a topic already discussed here. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725947/how-to-setup-android-sdk-2-0)

If you mean you want to build against Android 2.0, you should simply right click on the project, go to properties, and then Android. You should see a list of targets. Simply check the one right for you.

Comment: Thank i do this but i got the answer which help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

Go to sdk manager and install required lvl from it

Comment: i also do this.but Android2.0 Eclair can`t Display Here so what to do Now?

Answer (score 0):

Goto window->android sdk manager and check the boxes you want to install. One of the checkboxes also concerns the avd, install it and then goto window->avd manager to create a new AVD.

Comment: ok i do this but i wnat api level 5 android2.0eclair but it can`t display.and any other api level has been display.

Comment: Yes Eclair isnt available in the sdk manager, cant you use any other API's?

Comment: what you say?i also use the any other api`s in my Eclipse.

Comment: Yes you can use Android 2.1 or Android 1.6, why are you trying to use Eclair particularly?

Comment: because if you see the api level-5 is only come in Android2.2Eclair. so i use this.

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: why refresh? i can`t under stand what you say dear?

Comment: @Zala Janaksinh If someone writes something that you do not understand, please search it in dictionary. [Rephrase](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/Rephrase): *express in an alternative way.*